# Dijit form stops validating when mvc Group is used in it

Tags: model-view-controller, dojo

I have a page which uses dijit/form/Form to validate all of the form widgets in it.

Validation works correctly if I put widgets directly under the Form (tag).

Once I surround the widgets with a dojox/mvc/Group (within the form), Form validation stops completely and none of the widgets seem to validate when I call Form::validate().

Debugging the Dojo code shows that nested widgets are never considered validatable in the Form so when I surround widgets with Group they get excluded from validation.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT from `dijit/form/_FormMixin#_getDescendantFormWidgets()` and `dijit/_WidgetBase#getChildren()`, the issue can be solved by adding `data-dojo-mixins="dijit/_Container"` to the element having `data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group"`.

Also (though I'm not sure if it meets your requirement), dojox/mvc/tests/test_mvc_new_loan-stateful.html example shows form validation solution with dojox/mvc.

Hope it helps.

Best, Akira

Comment: Thanks Akira, I will check that test page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no easy way to solve this with dijit/form/Form. At the very least, it should be subclassed or monkey-patched to make it consider nested widgets.

However, it seems that dojox/form/Manager handles nested widgets properly, so I have switched to it.

Switching to Manager required some refactoring since it cannot be simply converted into an object with dom-form (dijit/form/Form can be converted).

HTML code before:

```
  <div
    id="_pg_detailForm"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form"
    encType="multipart/form-data" 
    action="" method=""
  >
    ... form widgets (surrounded with MVC Groups...etc)
  </div>
```

After:

```
  <form id="_pg_detailForm">
    <div
      id="_pg_detailFormManager"
      data-dojo-type="dojox/form/Manager"
    >
      ... form widgets (surrounded with MVC Groups...etc)

    </div>
  </form>
```